# How to pass 2 variables to a php document with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, datepicker

Hello I have two text inputs which get their values from a datepicker.
What I want to do is when user selects the two dates script pass these two values to a php document in which I make some checks and I return some html.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

(#to and $from are 2 input texts)

```
$(document).ready(dateinput_change);
  function dateinput_change(){
    $('#to').change(check_availability);
    $('#from').change(check_availability);
  }
  function check_availability(){
    var to=$('#to').attr('value');
    var from=$('#from').attr('value');
    $.get("get_availability.php?to="+ to +"&from="+ from, show_availability);
  }
  function show_availability(available){
    $('#availability').html(available);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use the ajax method. But you could write the following.

```
 $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "get_availability.php",
          data: "to=" + to + "&from=" + from,
          success: show_availibility
     });
```

Comment: You should use `data: {to: to, from: from},`

Comment: You certainly can. In fact, Nikos could write:

$.get("get_availability.php", { to: to, from: from}, show_availibility );

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't return anything. Can you imagine why that happens?

Comment: Try binding the change event to your selectors, rather than putting them in a function. e.g.

 $('#to, #from').bind('change', check_availability);